# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in Tkinker Movie Booking GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

(I hardly know tkinter)

When I run my code and select a seat and click on bookseat, it gives me an error saying:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "main.py", line 105, in bookseat
    seatList[i[0][i[1]]]['bg'] = 'brown'
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Please Help!

Comment: You probably have misplaced brackets in `[i[0][i[1]]]` maybe it should be `[i[0]][i[1]]`